# Find Control Issue in Gridview Paging

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on Gridview Concepts. I have a Checkbox column and a paging in my Gridview. I should find the Checkbox control from the Gridview. Its working fine for the First page, but incase of second page I'm not able to find the checkbox control.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview1.Rows)
{
  CheckBox chkGrid = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkGrid");
}
```

How can I find the checkbox control for the second page, as well as, for the other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://odetocode.com/articles/116.aspx AND http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs. HAVE A LOOK

Comment: Cant get any idea from that links.

Comment: do you want to find the control from the previous page? if yes then you may use cross page posting . and add previouspage directive.